# VCAST Infinite Loop Testing

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, vectorcast

I apply branch and statement coverage testing for my units using VCAST. However, since some units contain infinite while loops (while(1)), when I execute my test cases, the report results timeout. I had previously activated a setting in the configuration settings that would exit the loop and end the execution after a while in infinite loops, but I don't remember that setting now. Can you help me on how I should configure my configuration settings? Thanks in advance.